# Get a list of max values per key in a list of list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I need a list of max values per key. In the following example:

```
mydict = {
"day1": [[9],[2],[3]], 
"day2": [[4],[5],[6]],
"day3": [[3],[2],[1]]
}
```

what I need is something like `result=[9,6,3]`

I tried:

```
result = max(map(max, i) for i in worksheet.values())
```

but it just returns me the first key value. As always, thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could use simple indexing, a solution using the latter will not scale for input with arbitrary depths. Instead, use recursion with `max`:

```
flattened = lambda x:[c for h in [[i] if not isinstance(i, list) else flattened(i) for i in x] for c in h]
mydict = {'day2': [[4], [5], [6]], 'day3': [[3], [2], [1]], 'day1': [[9], [2], [3]]}
result = {a:max(flattened(b)) for a, b in mydict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'day2': 6, 'day3': 3, 'day1': 9}
```

With data n-levels deep:

```
data = {3:[4, 5, 2, [4, [53, [4, 200]]]], 4:[[[56, 3], [4, [[5]]]]]}
new_result = [max(flattened(i)) for i in data.values()]
```

Output:

```
[200, 56]
```

Comment: Thank you @Ajax1234 ! Is there any way to get the sorted results? I mean, to get `[9,6,3]`  instead of `[6, 3, 9]` (acording to sorted order of keys...). I tried: `[max(flattened(i)) for i in sorted(worksheet.values())]`but didn't seem to work..

Comment: @Victor Dictionaries are unsorted, thus, the order of `dict.values` is not guaranteed. However, you can use `dict.items` and use a dictionary comprehension to better retain the overall structure. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: @Victor From Python 3.7 dictionaries will be guaranteed to [keep insertion order](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html). I'm not %100 sure but I think the feature is already there in 3.6 just not officially.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to get rid of one layer of nesting:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> 
>>> mydict = {
... "day1": [[9],[2],[3]], 
... "day2": [[4],[5],[6]],
... "day3": [[3],[2],[1]]
... }
>>> 
>>> list(map(max, map(chain.from_iterable, mydict.values())))
[9, 6, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with this nested list comprehension:

```
result = [max([i for sublist in mydict[k] for i in sublist]) for k in mydict]

>>> result
[9, 6, 3]
```

**Explanation:**

The inner list comprehension:

```
[i for sublist in mydict[k] for i in sublist]
```

Flattens each list (each list of lists in your dictionary values). You then take the `max()` for each of these, when you iterate through `for k in my dict`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dict with the max values for each list of lists and using [Alex Martelli's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) list [flattening pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/298607):

```
>>> {k:max(e for sl in l for e in sl) for k,l in mydict.items()} 
{'day2': 6, 'day3': 3, 'day1': 9}
```

Same general technique, you can create a list of max values:

```
>>> [max(e for sl in l for e in sl) for l in mydict.values()] 
[6, 3, 9]
```

(Which is of limited value IMHO since Python dicts are unordered in Python prior to 3.6)

Of course, this can be sorted if desired:

```
>>> sorted([max(e for sl in l for e in sl) for l in mydict.values()], reverse=True) 
[9, 6, 3]
```

(But then which key has which max? It is unclear from your question if that matters...)

Comment: thank you very much, @dawg ...I wasn't aware about dictionaries aren't sorted, but i will really keep your answer in mind about how to create a new dict with max values only, it would be useful for me in future applications. Once again, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're having is that the internal elements are also lists, so you have to unpack them. My first suggestion would be that the structure of `mydict` is wrong if each of those inner lists is supposed to be only one element long. Possibly  it look like this instead:

```
mydict = {
    "day1": [9, 2, 3], 
    "day2": [4, 5, 6],
    "day3": [3, 2, 1]
}
```

Alternatively, you'll need to flatten the inner lists. I might do something like:

```
[max(sum(lists, [])) for lists in mydict.values()]
```

Note that this version depends on the dictionary being ordered (which is true for the recent enough versions of python, but definitely not all versions.

Comment: Never ever use [`sum` to concatenate lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/7207392).

Comment: Thank you very much, Julian! You guys are terrific! Unfortunately I'm afraid I need a list of lists, sometimes a few of them will cointain multiple values, I just used a single value per list to keep it simple on the example. Once again thank you very much for your time and dedication.